# Can a GridView be made to be click-able and run a new SQL query based on which row you click?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that populates with a list of security reports. One of the fields that it does not show is the long text that is in the report. Depending on circumstances, there may be multiple reports. I have it set up to display the latest report, but if the user wants to view a different report that is being listed in the gridview, they have to type the report number into a text box and click a button.

Is there a way to make this work by clicking on the line of the gridview?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that by implement a handler for the GridView.RowDataBound Event. See ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx)) for more details concerning the event.

Here is a typical implementation sample of such a handler

```
protected void MyGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // Check the type of Row if necessary 
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // Do some processing here, in your case you can add onClick event handling for example
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick" /* Your event handler here */);



    }
}
```

You could use the **GridViewRowEventArgs parameters Row property** to retrieve the clicked row and use any data/information that is related to it for example

Comment: How would the databound event on a gridview fire when the row is clicked? As far as my knowledge goes the rowdatabound event will only fire after you call the databind() method?